# useEffect return an empty array

Tags: react-native, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to render data from my database

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import api from '../../Services/api';

function ProviderList(){
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState([]);

  async function loadingProvider(){
    const response = await api.get('providers');
    setProvider(response.data);
    console.log(provider);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadingProvider();
  }, []);
  

  return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{provider.name}</Text>   
    </View> 
    
  )
}

export default ProviderList;
```

When my page is rendered, the provider console.log is an empty array but when I save my project and the page reload, the data is returned. I read that it's because hooks are rendered right after the first page render, but I need to render this data when the page starts, and I don't know how to do it. Someone could help?

Comment: Does conditional rendering do what you want?  So return {provider.length !== 0 ? <what you want to render here/> : <></>}

Comment: I just want to get the API data to render on the screen, I haven't created the components yet. I just use console.log to see if the data was returning, but the only thing that returned was an empty array

Comment: You have declared `provider` as an empty array but using it as an object `provider.name`. That seems incorrect.

Comment: @MohitMutha yes, i tried to use useState to change the provider's value by the data returned from the API on response.data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you error is log data

```js
    setProvider(response.data);
    console.log(provider); //here the error
```

you can't log state immediately after update it 
the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) say that

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later

for log listen for provider change like that

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(provider); //log will work here
  }, [provider]);
```

and you have another error here `{provider.name}`

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{provider.name}</Text> //provider is array not abject
    </View>
```

this will work for you

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

function ProviderList(){
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState([]);

  async function loadingProvider(){
    const response = {data : [1,2,3,4]}; //replace this with api
    setProvider(response.data);
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(provider); //log will work here
  }, [provider]);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    loadingProvider();
  }, []);
  

  return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>provider length is : {provider.length}</Text>   
    </View> 
    
  )
}

export default ProviderList;
```